# Make jQuery Line Animation move on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a line on my website that animates under the anchor element when that anchor element has been clicked. I would like to get it to also animate when the user scrolls to the corresponding section without them having to click on the link, but i seem to be having some trouble doing this.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<header id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <nav id="example-one">
                <ul>
                    <li class="current_page_item"><a class="nav" href="#home">Welcome</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav" href="#featuredWork">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav" href="#caseStudy">Case Study</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav" href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

**jQuery**

```
$( window ).load(function() {

//Grabs the height value of the header, can use this variable later for css media queieres instead of hardcoding pixel value
var headerHeight = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;

//Sets top values of sections to later be used in colour change segment



//Allows for smooth scrolling
var $root = $('html, body');
$('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top - headerHeight
    }, 600);
    return false;
});

//Change colour of header bar and elements based on which section the user is on
$(document).scroll(function() {

    var top1 = $('#home').offset().top;
    var top2 = $('#featuredWork').offset().top - headerHeight;
    var top3 = $('#caseStudy').offset().top - headerHeight;
    var top4 = $('#about').offset().top - headerHeight;
    var top5 = $('#contact').offset().top - headerHeight;


  if ($(document).scrollTop() >= top1 && $(document).scrollTop() < top2) {
    $('#header').css('background-color', '#dadfe0');
    $('.nav').css('color', '#21303f');
  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= top2 && $(document).scrollTop() < top3) {
    $('#header').css('background-color', '#21303f');
    $('.nav').css('color', '#dadfe0');
  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= top3 && $(document).scrollTop() < top4) {
    $('#header').css('background-color', '#dadfe0');
    $('.nav').css('color', '#21303f');
  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= top4 && $(document).scrollTop() < top5) {
    $('#header').css('background-color', '#21303f');
    $('.nav').css('color', '#dadfe0');
  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= top5) {
    $('#header').css('background-color', '#dadfe0');
    $('.nav').css('color', '#21303f');
  }  

});

//Magic line

$(function() {


    /* Add Magic Line markup via JavaScript, because it ain't gonna work without */

    $("#example-one").append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");


    /* Cache it */
    var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

    $magicLine
        .width($(".current_page_item").width())
        .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left)

    $("#example-one li").find("a").click(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();

        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        });   
    });


});

});
```

I've included the entire jQuery file as I already have some scrolling functionality in place for header colour change.

Also here is my portfolio site as it stands now, so you can get a better picture of what I'm trying to achieve.

[Portfolio Site - Work In Progress](http://kylebinger.com)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/) to get help with your menu :)

The JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");

        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```